# How to make sure that fscanf() returns an overflow error for %ld?

Tags: c

According to the man page, fscanf returns EOF on error, but nowhere can I find specified if overflow is an error.
I heard that strtol() is probably closely linked to this process, and what it does is consume all the numbers in the file, and then return LONG_MIN on underflow, or LONG_MAX on overflow, and sets errno to ERANGE. But the question is will it pass on the error to fscanf().

I don't want to consume an infinite amount of numbers, and I want to 100% be sure that fscanf() will return EOF in a case of overflow.

How do I do that? `%10ld`?

Comment: " if overflow is an error." --> With `fscanf("%ld", ...` or `"%10ld"`, overflow is undefined behavior (UB).  With `"%9ld"` there is no chance of overflow, just potentially unread text.

Comment: "will it pass on the error to fscanf()." --> No.

Comment: "I want to 100% be sure that fscanf() will return EOF in a case of overflow" --> Not possible without UB.

Comment: "I don't want to consume an infinite amount of numbers," --> Up to how many numbers do you want to consume?  Post has about 4 questions, perhaps clearly identify the one of most interest?  The title question's answer is: not possible.

Comment: When converting strings to integers in C, **only** the `strto*` functions have guaranteed, well-defined behavior on overflow. `*scanf`, and the `ato*` functions, all have undefined behavior on overflow.

Comment: `%10ld` won't prevent overflow on a machine with 32-bit `long` (since 9999999999 is a 34-bit number), and of course `%9ld` will skip some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `EOF` due to integer overflow would violate the C standard. Setting `errno` to `ERANGE` on integer overflow is not specified by the standard (indeed, the conversion results in *undefined behavior*)<sup>1</sup>, but library functions are allowed to set `errno` to a non-zero value on success.

Presumably, the implementation that sets `errno` to `ERANGE` on integer overflow would allow the caller to detect this error by setting `errno = 0;` before the call:

```
    int val;
    int ret;

    errno = 0;
    ret = fscanf(fp, "%d", &val);
    if (ret == EOF) {
        /* Normal error. */
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        /* val not read. */
    } else {
        /* val read. */
        if (errno == ERANGE) {
            /* There was an overflow. */
        }
    }
```

In the glibc C library (at least up to version 2.36), this does not work properly for integer types that are narrower than `long`.  For example, on my 64-bit GNU/Linux system (with 64-bit `long` and 32-bit `int`), reading the input 12345678901 into an `int` does not set `errno`, but reading the input 12345678901234567890 into an `int` does set `errno` to `ERANGE`. Not setting `errno` on integer overflow is *not* a bug in the glibc library. From what I can tell, the only place where this error is documented is in the Linux man-pages from release 3.01 up to at least 6.01 at the time of writing. In my humble opinion, the scanf(3) man page should not mention `ERANGE` at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> As mentioned by @chux in the question comments, converting an input number that cannot be represented by the target object type results in *undefined behavior* (unless the assignment suppression flag `*` was used). Refer to C17 7.21.6.2/10 (for `fscanf`), 7.29.2.2/10 (for `fwscanf`):

> [...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

It seems strange that a conforming program that uses `scanf` to read an integer without carefully specifying a maximum field width cannot prevent undefined behavior caused by incorrect or malicious input. The optional "Annex K" functions such as `scanf_s` *allow* the implementation to treat the incorrect input as a runtime constraint violation, but do not require it to do so.

> "A strange game. The only winning move is not to play." ― Joshua/WOPR, WarGames (1983)

Comment: My read of "Unless assignment suppression ..." is that `*` suppresses assignment, but that is not part of the "... if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.". IMO, overflow is UB with or without `*`.  Yet I see how it is reasonable to view otherwise.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica My take on it is that the text refers to *the* object so there has to be an object. If it said "or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in an object of the appropriate type" I would agree with you.

Comment: So if scanf functions are bad, why do people use them? I mean, I would use them to read a standardized type of file where it's 99% chance it will all be ok and the user's fault if it isn't. But I hoped to do everything defensively and securely. Fetching chunks from a file into a buffer, reading it, and then using fseek() to return the cursor to the correct position looks to me like it would introduce more problems than it would solve...